# Meaning of "In 1995, Eric Cantona was at the height of his powers."

Tags: meaning

> "In 1995, Eric Cantona was at the height of his powers."

Does it mean Cantona made great achievements in 1995? Or could it mean he possessed powers because it is his footballing heyday?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can be answered by checking dictionaries and grammars (it might be welcome on English Language Learners if some research were shown)

Comment: [*When an activity, situation, or organization is **at its height**, it is at its most successful, powerful, or intense.*](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/at%20the%20height%20of%20one's%20power) If in 1995 Cantona was at the *height of his powers*, that's when his powers were greatest. If, on the other hand, he was *height of his profession*, that would mean he was *one of the most noted figures in his area of expertise* (with the implication that he never rose any higher, and almost certainly slipped *down* the "rankings" in subsequent years).

Comment: @TimLymington Yes,it should be asked in Learners.I used google translate,it doesn't help.I should checking dictionaries,google translate is not the right tool.

Comment: @mnors: I suppose you've got your answer from the comment, so it doesn't make much difference now if the question is closed (I myself closevoted after posting my first comment). But I think if you have any more questions like this you really should ask them at  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). They'd probably get better (full-sized) answers there, and wouldn't be so likely to get downvoted or closed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I got it.Closevoted mean "When a question reaches 5 close votes, it is marked [on hold], and will no longer accept answers" and then [closed]?

Comment: @mnors: Yes. Questions are closed (placed "on hold") for many reasons - sometimes the asker can edit the question (to clarify exactly what he wants to know, for example), and it might get re-opened. But in your case the question probably *will* get closed, and it's unlikely to be re-opened because for native speakers it's effectively General Reference that could be looked up in a dictionary if anyone happened not to understand the expression. You have asked on the wrong site, I think.

Comment: A perfectly legitimate question, if we see what the OP means to ask. Was about to answer when it earned its fifth close vote.

Answer (score -1):

> "In 1995, Eric Cantona was at the height of his powers."

This sentence means that from the perspective of 1996, or any year up to 2013, Eric Cantona achieved his personal best as a footballer in 1995.  In other words, 1995 was his peak year.  The assumption is, I suspect, that his performance went downhill from 1995, on, though his decline may not have been drastic, of course.